# Capper indents bottle cap. Is this ok?

Tags: equipment, bottling, carbonation, capping

I have a standard, hand held bottle capper and when I am using it I am getting indentations in the cap. The larger problem is that I am having issues with inconsistent carbonation and want to determine if the capper is the problem.It seems like there could be 100 reasons why there is inconsistent carbonation but I am trying to rule out the capper.

Here is a photo of what the cap looks like after applying what seems to be standard pressure when capping the bottles. I have also tried using varying pressure lighter and stronger when capping and noticed no noticeable difference.

[image: Dented Bottle Cap]

[image]

[image]

Has anyone else had this issue and can you confirm it has or has not had an effect on you carbonation?

And no its not on there so light that the carbonation escapes.

Comment: Can you add a pic of your capper? I've never seen this happen with mine, a two handled red hand capper (not sure on what kind, perhaps a butterfly capper?)

Comment: Got it with a starter kit. Not sure I'm happy with it either way but need to figure this out before I invest more money in equipment etc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My capper does this too.  It's not been an issue for our beer.  If it was leaking I'd think you might see some evidence around the top.

Comment: Yeah, there has not been any leaking. Just noticed other home brewers I talk to have not had this issue, so I wanted to rule it out. Thank you.

Comment: If you are worried about leaking, drop one of your beers (cap facing upwards) in a bucket of water. Bubbles are bad. :)

Comment: My capper also makes that indentation, if I squeeze a little too hard, but there never seemed to be a problem with the carbonation level.

Comment: Mine makes marks too, espoecially if i use too much pressure or if I get a little off center/level. not a full circle in my case, just a partial which is how I know it is from leaning too far to one side or the other.